# SQL TO_DATE format error

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I wrote this statement to get the 1st day of the previous month

```
select '01.' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MM.yyyy') from dual
```

Output: `01.02.2016`

If I use `TO_DATE` to format I get the following error: `not a valid month`

My current not working solution:

```
select TO_DATE('01.' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MM.yyyy')) from dual
```

Thanks for any help / advices

Comment: Tag dbms used! TO_CHAR etc are product specific functions.

Comment: Added `oracle` tag based on the combination of `to_char()` and `sysdate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a format String for to_date, too:

```
select TO_DATE('01.' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MM.yyyy'), 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual
```

But it is simpler to use trunc, as proposed by lad2025.

Answer (score 3):

You could calculate it using [`TRUNC`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm):

```
SELECT TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'mm') AS result
FROM dual;
```